# html5 canvas - multiple drawing instances

Tags: html, canvas

When trying to run multiple drawings in canvas I've noticed that with the wrong timing things could get messed up.

I.e. have canvas draw a line out via a interval; then duplicate that (line draw) multiple times and set each one's stroke color to be different... In the end, you get stroke colors going to other lines and etc...

Is there a way to have multiple drawing instances (context.ctx) that can't interfere with others?

Example of interval code below:

```
    it.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200,200,0,.1)"
    it.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,22,.01)";
    var p = i.p.split(",");

    var rp = setInterval(function(){
        if(cc>=20){
            clearInterval(rp);
            it.ctx.strokeRect( p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] );
            return;
        }
        it.ctx.fillRect( p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] );
        cc++;
    },30);
```

Comment: Please post some code. What you are describing should not be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have other code running in between calls to this interval function that modify `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle`, you'll need to explicitly set these values each time you draw on the canvas:

```
var p = i.p.split(",");
var rp = setInterval(function(){
    it.ctx.save(); // Save the current canvas styles.

    it.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200,200,0,.1)";
    it.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,22,.01)";

    if(cc>=20){
        clearInterval(rp);
        it.ctx.strokeRect( p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] );
    }
    else {
        it.ctx.fillRect( p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3] );
        cc++;
    }

    it.ctx.restore(); // Restore the original canvas styles.
},30);
```

If you don't set your `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle` in the interval function, the canvas will use whatever the outside "background" code has established.

Comment: Great point, however, what happens if I have multiple intervals running, couldn't one of those points flip stroke to another interval's style?

Comment: Got it.  Would you recommend using the save / res funcs?

Comment: Yes, `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` will help you maintain state within your application.